# Making forecast using LSTM model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, prediction

I have been trying very hard to making a LSTM model and after I trained and fit the model, I want to use it to forecast new data. I use 12 month data (12 rows) to predict the next month data.

However, when I input the 12 month data, there were 12 predictions which should only be just one.

Could anyone help to see if there is something wrong with my model structure? I'm quite new to this so I'm a little confused.

You can see that my input shape is (12,13) (13 here is because I use 13 features)

```
def build_model(hp):
    grid_model = Sequential()
    grid_model.add(LSTM(hp.Int('input_unit',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32),return_sequences=True,\
                        input_shape=(data_train_x.shape[1],data_train_x.shape[2]))) # (12,13) time steps + features
    for i in range(hp.Int('n_layers', 1, 3)):
        grid_model.add(LSTM(hp.Int(f'lstm_{i}_units',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32),return_sequences=True))
    grid_model.add(LSTM(hp.Int('last_layer_unit',min_value=32,max_value=512,step=32),return_sequences=False))
    grid_model.add(Dropout(hp.Float('Dropout_rate',min_value=0.1,max_value=0.5,step=0.1)))
    grid_model.add(Dense(1, activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation',values=['relu', 'sigmoid'],default='relu')))

    optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', values = ['adam', 'rmsprop', 'adadelta'])
    
    grid_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizer ,metrics = ['mse'])
    
    #set learning rate
    learning_rate = hp.Choice('lr', [0.02, 0.01, 0.005])
    K.set_value(grid_model.optimizer.learning_rate, learning_rate)
    
    return grid_model
```

I used a batch size of 10 here

```
    tuner.search(x=data_train_x, y=data_train_y, epochs = 50, batch_size =10, 
                 validation_split = 0.15, shuffle = False,
                 callbacks = [stop_early])
```

This is how I make predictions, tensor_pred has the shape (1,12,13)

```
new_pred = hypermodel.predict(tensor_pred); new_pred
```

After the inverse scaling, I got the following results.

```
array([756459.4 , 753678.1 , 724612.6 , 727920.5 , 721956.  , 710755.5 ,
       717139.7 , 713023.06, 705151.2 , 705286.5 , 700536.7 , 691794.06],
      dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

12 is your batch size, so your prediction shape is (12,), which is just one prediction for each input. You are still correct.

Comment: Oh thanks for making me realize about the batch size. I actually didn't know why the batch size matters here. Do you mind explaining a bit more about why this leads to a prediction shape like this? When I fit the model, I think my batch size is 10 (I have updated my codes to show you).

Comment: The batch size is the number of inputs we give to the model. A batch size of 10 is similar to “this input batch has 10 images” or equivalent. The number of outputs of the model will equal the batch size. When you set 10, you are using 10 for training, but you are using 12 when prediction. This is OK by the way, so nothing is wrong when using different batch size when training vs predicting.

Comment: Each element in the output corresponds to the element in the input. For example, if you output tensor has shape (12,), then output[0] is the prediction of input[0], and so on.

Comment: I see! I chose my output to be of shape (1,) as you can see from dense(1). Since I am interested in using X1...Xn and Y1..Yn to predict Yn+1. So I'm still a little confused why the prediction has 12 numbers (I think should just only be 1 number)

Comment: If you find this helpful, consider marking it “answered” for other folks to see :)